# How to map same step with multiple Job in spring

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on spring batch module, and use case is, we have list of steps what I have mentioned below. These steps consider as Global steps. Now these steps need to be map as per client basis. For example for client a only step 'batchUpload', 'bankTerminalValidation', 'incorporateStagedExternalTransactionsIntoExternalTransaction' needs to be run. and for client b 'batchUploadStep', 'externalTransactionMatching,'incorporateExternalTransactionData' needs to be run and so on. Is there any efficient way through which can do this. In this example processBatch id bean is autowired with one batchService where jobluncher is call.

```
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(processBatch, getBatchJobParameters(batch));
            log.info("Process Batch Job execution {} ", jobExecution);
```

Here I do not want to change the above code. I am thinking like we need to implement the logic for different clients.

```
<job id="processBatch" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" parent="abstractAggregatorBatch">
        <step id="batchUpload" next="bankTerminalValidation">
            <tasklet ref="batchUploadStep" allow-start-if-complete="true">
                <transaction-attributes timeout="#{batchTransactionTimeout}"/>
            </tasklet>
        </step>
        <step id="bankTerminalValidation" next="incorporateStagedExternalTransactionsIntoExternalTransaction">
            <tasklet ref="bankTerminalValidationStep" allow-start-if-complete="true">
                <transaction-attributes timeout="300"/>             
            </tasklet>
        </step>
        <step id="incorporateStagedExternalTransactionsIntoExternalTransaction" next="externalTransactionMatching">
            <tasklet ref="incorporateStagedExternalTransactionsIntoExternalTransactionStep" allow-start-if-complete="true">
                <transaction-attributes timeout="#{batchTransactionTimeout}"/>
            </tasklet>
        </step>
        <step id="externalTransactionMatching" next="incorporateExternalTransactionData">
            <tasklet ref="externalTransactionMatchingStep" allow-start-if-complete="true"/>
        </step>
        <step id="incorporateExternalTransactionData" next="extraBatchTransactionCheck">
            <tasklet ref="incorporateExternalTransactionDataStep"/>
        </step>
        <step id="extraBatchTransactionCheck" next="bankChargeValidation">
            <tasklet ref="extraBatchTransactionCheckStep"/>
        </step>
        <step id="bankChargeValidation" next="pineChargeCalculation" parent="abstractAggregatorStep">
            <tasklet task-executor="asyncExecutor" throttle-limit="${threadpool.coresize}">
                <chunk commit-interval="1" reader="uniqueFeeStructureIdReader" writer="bankChargeValidationItemWriter">
                    <listeners>
                        <listener ref="batchContextListener"/>
                    </listeners>
                </chunk>
                <transaction-attributes timeout="#{batchTransactionTimeout}"/>
            </tasklet>
            <listeners merge="true">
                <listener ref="bankChargeValidationStepExecutionListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </step>
        <step id="pineChargeCalculation" next="bankMprReconGeneration" parent="abstractAggregatorStep">
            <tasklet task-executor="asyncExecutor" throttle-limit="${threadpool.coresize}">
                <chunk commit-interval="1" reader="uniqueAggregatorMerchantIdReader" writer="pineChargeCalculationItemWriter">
                    <listeners>
                        <listener ref="batchContextListener"/>
                    </listeners>
                </chunk>
                <transaction-attributes timeout="#{batchTransactionTimeout}"/>
            </tasklet>
            <listeners merge="true">
                <listener ref="pineChargeCalculationStepExecutionListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </step>
        <step id="bankMprReconGeneration">
            <tasklet ref="bankMprReconGenerationStep">
                <transaction-attributes timeout="#{batchTransactionTimeout}"/>
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
```

can somebody helped me how can I achieve this thing.

Comment: To confirm what you're attempting to do, you are looking for a way for users to define a job with their custom steps that includes some other boilerplate steps?  If that's correct, I'll provide my answer.

Comment: yes, I am looking for same